# glmer categorical fixed effects estimate missing? -R

Tags: r, mixed-model, categorical-data, fixed-effects-model

I posted a question recently regarding general linear mixed effects models, and I think I may have finally specified the glmer model correctly. I am interested in finding any differences in home range sizes between parks, between 2 time periods (wet and dry season). I have added individual ID as a random effect and year nested within ID as some IDs have multiple measurements for different years. I have 8 levels for "season", and 2 levels for "park". My question is: why is the 8th level for "season" omitted from the fixed estimates? 
Also, by  looking at the p values, am I correct in stating that home range sizes for season 3 are significantly different between parks? I am definitely new to mixed models and would appreciate any help.

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: gaussian  ( log )
Formula: homerange ~ park * season + (1 | ID/year)
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
2271.9   2332.7  -1117.0   2233.9      162 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.7332 -0.4334 -0.0220  0.3912  4.1532 

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
year:ID  (Intercept)  275.2   16.59   
ID       (Intercept)  123.1   11.10   
Residual             1997.7   44.70   
Number of obs: 181, groups:  year:ID, 38; ID, 17

Fixed effects:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    4.07652    0.10395  39.217  < 2e-16 ***
park1          0.35882    0.10381   3.456 0.000548 ***
season1       -0.08571    0.13749  -0.623 0.533024    
season2        0.06915    0.12411   0.557 0.577380    
season3        0.04081    0.12784   0.319 0.749554    
season4        0.51415    0.20602   2.496 0.012574 *  
season5        0.01990    0.13948   0.143 0.886525    
season6       -0.55669    0.22691  -2.453 0.014152 *  
season7       -0.32262    0.18747  -1.721 0.085256 .  
park1:season1 -0.22670    0.13761  -1.647 0.099482 .  
park1:season2 -0.18563    0.12389  -1.498 0.134042    
park1:season3 -0.25638    0.12789  -2.005 0.045005 *  
park1:season4  0.92146    0.20639   4.465 8.02e-06 ***
park1:season5 -0.17337    0.13925  -1.245 0.213114    
park1:season6 -0.10128    0.22720  -0.446 0.655756    
park1:season7  0.10990    0.18755   0.586 0.557901    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: how did you estimate your model? If I use ` family = gaussian("log")` within `glmer`, I get the error, "`response must be numeric`". Maybe you can add a line with the command to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Season estimates are set in referance to season 8..same with park levels are set in reference to park 2...i.e. the estimate for these are 0. This is a result of you using categorical effects. So to  get a prediction for park 2 in season 8, it would just be the intercept.  Interpreting the interaction term park1 by season 3 is more ambiguous with categorical effects. I would suggest doing tukey pairwise tests of park by season.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up a bit. So, for an estimate of park 1 in season 8 as well, a pairwise test would help?

Comment: To compare to park 2 season 8 or to compare different seasons in park 1

Comment: Yes, just realized previous comment may be unclear